# Closed form of a recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I was given this problem:

**Given a set of $n$ elements, how many possible involutions can we form?**

I have managed to device this recurrence relation: $$t_n=t_{n-1}+(n-1)t_{n-2}$$
How can I form a **closed form** equation for this?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is np knpwn closed form.

Comment: No closed form?! Is this that much pathological?! @AndréNicolas

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000085 -- the closest I see to a "closed form" is something like $t_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \frac{n!}{(n-2k)!2^kk!}$

Comment: I think of no closed form as normal. This particular sequence has been much studied, and has good asymptotics.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_%28mathematics%29#Summation_formula_and_approximation

Comment: Phew! Can you give me links to a proof? @MarcusStuhr

Comment: The Wiki link explains the derivation of that expression

Comment: Oh... I see... Thanks a lot... @MarcusStuhr